# ORACLE APEX 5.0 Region Source query with html

Tags: oracle-apex

The query works well in Apex 4.2 but in 5.0 I receive error message in line 1

Query cannot be parsed within the Builder. If you believe your query is syntactically correct, check the ''generic columns'' checkbox below the region source to proceed without parsing. ORA-00919: invalid function

```
select '<a href="f?    p='||&APP_ID.||':203:'||&SESSION.||'::::P203_ANO,P203_ID_PRJ:'||ANO||',3">'||   ANO||'</a>' as ANO,
 1 as id_prj,
 to_char(Muni) as "MUNI",
 to_char("Inscritos",'999G999G999G999G999G999G990') as "Inscritos",
 to_char("Instituições",'999G999G999G999G999G999G990') as "Instituições",
 to_char("Turmas",'999G999G999G999G999G999G990') as "Turmas",
 to_char("Beneficiários",'999G999G999G999G999G999G990') as "Beneficiários" ,
 to_char("Participantes",'999G999G999G999G999G999G990') as "Participantes" 
FROM 
  V_MOSTRA_ACU_MUNI_ENR
where 
 ano < (SELECT 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM dual)) 
FROM 
  dual)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: try adding the ";" at the end of the query.

Comment: Semicolon won't help. Does your query still work in SQL Developer? And use bind variables instead of substitution strings http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2012/02/apex-variables-in-sql.html

Comment: it looks like you want to have a column link in your report?why dont you use the built-in one for apex?its much easier to create. well, if you want that way then, try commenting each column starting from the first column and see if they run correctly.if it runs correctly with one column comment out, then that column or line is what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking at the error, it says `ORA-00919: invalid function`, then after looking at your code, the first line of **TO_CHAR** doesnt have enough parameters, while the next columns using **TO_CHAR** functions even though it satisfies the parameter requirement of the function, it will probably throw an error because of the **double qoutation marks** that you've used.

- > Use single qoutation marks to enclose string/s.

try this:

```
SELECT '<a href="f?    p='||&APP_ID.||':203:'||&SESSION.||'::::P203_ANO,P203_ID_PRJ:'||ANO||',3">'||   ANO||'</a>' as ANO,
        1 as id_prj,
        Muni,  
        TO_CHAR('Inscritos','999G999G999G999G999G999G990') as "Inscritos", 
        TO_CHAR('Instituições','999G999G999G999G999G999G990') as "Instituições",
        TO_CHAR('Turmas','999G999G999G999G999G999G990') as "Turmas",
        TO_CHAR('Beneficiários','999G999G999G999G999G999G990') as "Beneficiários" ,
        TO_CHAR('Participantes','999G999G999G999G999G999G990') as "Participantes" 
FROM 
  V_MOSTRA_ACU_MUNI_ENR
WHERE
 ano < (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM dual)) 
        FROM 
        dual)
```

Comment: No reason why you can't call to_char with only one parameter, though without knowing the definition of the table, it's hard to know how "Muni" will be interpreted. Double quotes just makes things unnecessarily difficult, not sure it would invoke an error here.

Answer (score 0):

It's your own code which is bugged, in particular your link construction. You are using static text substitution syntax while you should be using bind variable syntax. They are VERY different. If anything, it should've thrown an error in apex 4.2 just as well. Right now you're telling apex to do illogical things.

Please consider what you've written!
[Apex 5.0 docs on referencing session state](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/concept_ses_val.htm#HTMDB03011)
`&.` will replace the variable with the value of the variable BEFORE parsing the query, ie the actual query will alter when the value is different. This will cause you to send lots of nearly-identical queries to your database and should be avoided at all costs. Read this post by Scott Wesley: [APEX variables in SQL](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2012/02/apex-variables-in-sql.html).
Not that there are no usecases for static text substitutions, of course. But if you must use them in SQL it should be in a STRING. Though when you do use in PLSQL, think twice.

Your query SHOULD look like this:

```
select '<a href="f?    p='|| :APP_ID ||':203:'||:APP_SESSION ||'::::P203_ANO,P203_ID_PRJ:'||ANO||',3">'||   ANO||'</a>' as ANO,
 1 as id_prj,
```

This way the query will not alter based on application id or session.

*Note: OP posted this question on OTN too: [Oracle OTN Apex](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3934878)*